# How do I start/restart RealVNC Enterprise Server for Mac via the command line? 

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vncserver, realvnc

How do I start/restart RealVNC Enterprise Server for Mac via the command line?

Perhaps also how do I tell (via command line, whether RealVNC Enterprise Server is running or not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

got this feedback from RealVNC

A) Start Service-Mode VNC Server

```
sudo touch /etc/vnc/service/on
```

This will trigger the launch of the VNC Server launch daemon and user helper launch agent

B) Stop Service-Mode VNC Server

```
sudo rm /etc/vnc/service/on
sudo launchctl stop com.realvnc.vncserver
launchctl stop com.realvnc.vncserver_agent
```

C) Restart Service-Mode VNC Server

Same as A)

Reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/launchctl.1.html

Answer (score 3):

The article [Start VNC from command line and connect to Mac from Windows VNC client](http://technosense.blogspot.com/2009/03/start-vnc-from-command-line-and-connect.html) recommends:

Step 1: -- set privs

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers -privs -all
```

Step 2: -- Allow VNC clients

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes
```

Step 3: -- Set VNC password (change it at the end of the line (i.e. don't use supersecret))

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw supersecret
```

Step 4: -- Restart service

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -restart -agent -console
```

Comment: Isn't this about the built-in VNC server?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
which vncserver
which x0vncserver
man vncserver
man x0vncserver
```

This works on Ubuntu; OS X should be similar.

Comment: don't get a response on Mac Lion for this - I did note after posting a fall back may be to reboot remotely, but doesn't specifically address the question I posed I guess